# Unable to execute a powershell script as a custom extension using Terraform

Tags: powershell, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to execute a custom extension script on Azure Windows VM using terraform. This is a simple PS1 script that executes a msi file that was already downloaded and made available in Azure VM. Both PS1 and MSI files are available in VM at mentioned location (c:\temp)

Here's the high level script I execute

```
locals {
  shir_authorization_key = "asdkjfbdkjfb"
  powershell_script = "c:\\temp\\installGatewayOnLocalMachine.ps1"
  msi_file_location = "C:\\temp\\IntegrationRuntime_5.33.8649.1.msi"
  vm_name = "sdjkfgbsgb"
  vm_custom_extension_name = "somename01"
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "shir-vm-exclusive" {
  for_each = local.shir_exclusive_vm_ids
  name                             = local.vm_custom_extension_name
  virtual_machine_id               = each.value
  publisher                        = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                             = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version             = "1.9"
  settings                         = <<SETTINGS
  {   
    "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ${local.powershell_script} -path \"${local.msi_file_location}\" -authKey ${local.shir_authorization_key}"
  }
  SETTINGS
}
```

I'm not able to get this code to work. I keep receiving Bad JSON error or something like below

```
CI-terraform-plan FAILURE terraform plan failed due to     Error: "settings" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'I' in string escape code
    
      with module.dataFactory_instance01.azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.shir-vm-exclusive["/subscriptions/0c535c03-373b-4ce5-a538-ab1832d91e49/resourceGroups/rg-cus-gtmddp-dev-01/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VCAUSC117DEV01P"],
      on .terraform/modules/dataFactory_instance01/vmshirexclusive.tf line 61, in resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "shir-vm-exclusive":
      61:   settings                         = <<SETTINGS
      62:   {   
      63:     "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ${local.powershell_script} -path \"${local.msi_file_location}\" -authKey ${local.shir_authorization_key}"
      64:   }
      65:   SETTINGS
```

Instead of passing path parameter as variable, if I pass the actual values, everything works fine

```
"commandToExecute": "powershell ${local.powershell_script} -path \"C:\\temp\\IntegrationRuntime_5.33.8649.1.msi\" -authKey ${local.shir_authorization_key}"
```

Not sure if I need do any additional escaping in file path, when I pass as variable to terraform script. Can someone advice on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to execute a PowerShell script as a custom extension using Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully

The cause of the problem you are facing with your Terraform script is the way string interpolation and escaping work in the JSON configuration for the Azure VM custom extension. You need to make sure that the slashes (`/`) in the `commandToExecute` string, which are often used in Windows file paths, are correctly escaped when you use variables.

A backslash in JSON indicates an escape character. In your original script, the backslashes in the file path from the variable `local.msi_file_location` (`C:/temp/...`) are escape characters, so the JSON is malformed.

You can fix this problem by providing the correct path after each file according to the path.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Assuming you have a resource group already created
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "Venkat"
}

# Assuming you have a virtual machine already created
data "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "Venkat-Windows-VM"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

# Locals for the script and extension details
locals {
  shir_authorization_key = "Welcoe@123$"
  powershell_script      = "C:/Installer/Powershellscript.ps1"
  msi_file_location      = "C:/Installer/7z2301-x64.msi"
  vm_custom_extension_name = "demovk"
}

# Custom script extension to run on the existing VM
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "shir_vm_extension" {
  name                 = local.vm_custom_extension_name
  virtual_machine_id   = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
  {
    "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ${replace(local.powershell_script, "\\", "\\\\")} -path \"${replace(local.msi_file_location, "\\", "\\\\")}\" -authKey ${local.shir_authorization_key}"
  }
  SETTINGS
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Now the open `run` and make the command `appwiz.cpl` and check the progress

[image]